# Xpath for choosing next sibling

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have piece of HTML like this:

```
<dt>name</dt>
<dd>value</dd>
<dt>name2</dt>
<dd>value2</dd>
```

I want to find all places where the structure is incorrect, meaning there is no `dd` tag after `dt` tag.

I tried this:

```
//dt/following-sibling::dt
```

but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT** as noted by @Gaim, my original version failed to capture a terminal `dt`

```
string xml = @"
    <root>
    <dt>name</dt>
    <dd>value</dd>
    <dt>name2</dt>
    <dt>name3</dt>
    <dd>value3</dd>
    <dt>name4</dt>
    <dt>name5</dt>
    <dd>value5</dd>
    <dt>name6</dt>
    </root>
    ";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList nodes = 
    doc.SelectNodes("//dt[not(following-sibling::*[1][self::dd])]");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output is those `dt` nodes that do not have a `dd` immediately following them:

```
<dt>name2</dt>
<dt>name4</dt>
<dt>name6</dt>
```

What we are doing here is saying:

```
//dt
```

All `dt` nodes, anywhere....

```
[not(following-sibling::*[1]
```

....such that it's *not* the case that their first following sibling (whatever it is called)....

```
[self::dd]]
```

...is called `dd`.

Comment: +1 -- The XPath expression can be molten down to `//dt[following-sibling::*[1][self::dt]]`

Comment: @Tomalak Your XPath doesn't match all cases, look at my answer, you match only the first.

Comment: @Gaim: You are right. The `not()` approach is the correct one, I did not think about the case where a `<dt>` is last sibling.

Comment: any idea how to deal when <dd> is missing e.g. <b>label1</b> value1 <br> <b>label2</b>value2 <br>...... ?

Comment: see my new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745209/how-to-extract-a-list-of-label-value-with-scrapy-when-html-tag-are-missing

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure that I understand you but there is my solution. This XPath matches ALL `<dt>` which are not followed by `<dd>` directly. So There is test structure

```
<xml>
  <dt>name</dt> <!-- match -->

  <dt>name2</dt>
  <dd>value2</dd>

  <dt>name</dt>
  <dd>value</dd>

  <dt>name2</dt>  <!-- match -->
</xml>
```

There is the XPath

```
//dt[ name( following-sibling::*[1] ) != 'dd' ]
```

or

```
//dt[  not( following-sibling::*[1]/self::dd ) ]
```

they do same thing

Comment: +1 better than my original, which failed to capture a terminal dd-lacking dt