# getting value using xpath and dom in php

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

this the part of the html i want to parse:

```
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
<td>
Some text
<br>
<font color=brown>label0</font>Value0
<br>
<font color=brown>Label1</font>Value1.<br>
Some text
<br>

<font color=brown>Label2</font>Value2<br>
</td>
</table>

</center>
```

I want to get Value0 and Value1.

If i use this:

```
$index=$element->nodeValue;
```

where element is the query to the `.../font` I get the Label0,1,2. But I want the Value. How to do it? I can also give more code if it is necessary.

Comment: check http://phpmaster.com/php-dom-using-xpath/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try perhaps:

```
$index=$element->nextSibling->nodeValue;
```

To get the value of the node after the font node.

Answer (score 1):

```
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
<td>
Some text
<br>
<font color=brown>label0</font><span>Value0</span>
<br>
<font color=brown>Label1</font><span>Value1.</span><br>
Some text
<br>

<font color=brown>Label2</font>Value2<br>
</td>
</table>
</center>
```

try putting span just as above and instead of quering font query for span...
hope it will help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = '<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
<td>
Some text
<br>
<font color=brown>label0</font>Value0
<br>
<font color=brown>Label1</font>Value1.<br>
Some text
<br>

<font color=brown>Label2</font>Value2<br>
</td>
</table>
</center>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//font");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo trim( $node->nextSibling->nodeValue ) . "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your query matches only the `font` from the root. Remove the `//` in order to get all the `font` in the whole document.

Comment: @Jelmer Did you even try to run the code. It does exactly what the OP wants and is in accordance to the html structure posted. I am **fully** aware of what the `//` does. Try to fix your answer first which implies CSS usage and what not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php It states that the '//' is used to start from the root element. In this case the `<center>` is, But if you have a look at the question again. He states `this the part of the html i want to parse` In other words, the `<center>` is not the root.

Answer (score -1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$xpath->loadHTML('link/to/html');
$fonts = $xpath->query('font');
foreach ($fonts as $font){
    echo $font->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

The script above will echo all the values of that's what is inside the `<font>`.

But please, why aren't you using `CSS`?

- http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php
- [Xpath for choosing next sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092303/xpath-for-choosing-next-sibling)

Comment: I have not created that site. I just been told to parse some values from it, so I have to deal with the current format.