# how to extract a list of label value with scrapy when html tag are missing

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am currently processing a document with

```
<b> label1 </b>
value1 <br>
<b> label2 </b>
value2 <br>
....
```

I can't figure out a clean approach to xpath with scrapy.
here is my best implementation

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

section = hxs.select(..............)
values = section.select("text()[preceding-sibling::b/text()]"):
labels = section.select("text()/preceding-sibling::b/text()"):
```

but I am not comfortable with this approach for matching nodes of both lists through index. I'd rather iterate through 1 list  ( values or labels) and query the matching  nodes as relative xpath. Such as :

```
values = section.select("text()[preceding-sibling::b/text()]"):
for value in values:
    value.select("/preceding-sibling::b/text()"):
```

I have been tweaking this expression but always return no matchs

**UPDATE**

I am looking for robust method that will tolerate "noise", e.g. :

```
garbage1<br>
<b> label1 </b>
value1 <br>
<b> label2 </b>
value2 <br>
garbage2<br>
<b> label3 </b>
value3 <br>
<div>garbage3</div>
```

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: figure out a robust approach to matching label and values without risks of mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry I use lxml, but it will work the same with Scrapy's own selector.

For the specific HTML you have given this will work:

```
>>> s = """<b> label1 </b>
... value1 <br>
... <b> label2 </b>
... value2 <br>
... """
>>> 
>>> import lxml.html
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(s)
<Element span at 0x10fdcadd0>
>>> soup = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> soup.xpath("//text()")
[' label1 ', '\nvalue1 ', ' label2 ', '\nvalue2 ']
>>> res = soup.xpath("//text()")
>>> for i in xrange(0, len(res), 2):
...     print res[i:i+2]
... 
[' label1 ', '\nvalue1 ']
[' label2 ', '\nvalue2 ']
>>>
```

Edit 2:

```
>>> bs = etree.xpath("//text()[preceding-sibling::b/text()]")
>>> for b in bs:
...     if b.getparent().tag == "b":
...         print [b.getparent().text, b]
... 
[' label1 ', '\nvalue1 ']
[' label2 ', '\nvalue2 ']
[' label3 ', '\nvalue3 ']
```

Also for what it's worth, if you are looping over selected elements you want to do "./foo" in your xpath inside the for loop, not "/foo".

Comment: this implementation is just different from mine but isnot really more robust. See update in the question.