# Find next sibling element in Selenium, Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <p id='one'> 1A </p>
    <p id='two'> 2A </p>
    <p id='three'> 3A </p>
    <p id='four'> 4A </p>
    <p id='five'> 5A </p>
    <p id='six'> 6A </p>
    <p id='seven'> 7A </p>
</body>
```

I use the code below to get the first `p` tag element:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('one')
```

Now, how to find the next sibling of `elem`?

Comment: You are missing a ' at the line <p id='three> 3A </p>.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpath for choosing next sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092303/xpath-for-choosing-next-sibling)

Answer (score 38):

I want to correct Mark Rowlands's answer,. The correct syntax will be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='one']/following-sibling::p")
```

Answer (score 17):

We need to pass `elem` to a JavaScript function and execute it. We cannot use it's name inside the JS function when we are passing `elem` to it, but we can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Here's an example of how you can get the next sibling of `elem`:

```
next_sibling = driver.execute_script("""
    return arguments[0].nextElementSibling
""", elem)
```

Take a look at this little example of how `execute_script()` function works:

```
sum = driver.execute_script("""
    console.log(arguments[0].innerHTML) // will print innerHTML of the element in console logs of the page
    return arguments[1] + arguments[2]
""", elem, 5, 6)

print(sum) # 11
```

Comment: @user3679414 This should be considered as the correct answer, because fully general,  i.e. there is no need for a starting-point xpath. Just tested. +1

Answer (score 13):

Using Xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id, 'one']/following-sibling::p")
```