# Find next/closest button Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im working with selenium to automatically fill out some `<input>`s on my site. I have multiple inputs which are identical, each with an input field and a send button. I want to post a string in each input field and send it (the site does not reload).

```
input = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cdRecord')
for in in inputs:
    in.click()
    nr = str(randint(0, 1000))
    in.send_keys("..."+nr)
    NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@type="submit" and @title="next"]' #this does not work
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH).click()
```

I fetch all the `input` first and then iterate over them. The problem is that he fills out each input but always clicks the same button.

**So my Question is, how do I find the closest button?**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887592/find-next-sibling-element-in-python-selenium) but if I want to use the `xpath` and `following-sibling`  I also would need to fetch some `id` and change the path in each iteration like:

```
x = fetch id from the input field?
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id, "x"]/following-sibling::button")
```

Is there a simple solution to find the closest element to the chosen element?

Comment: If these `INPUT`s are in a form, all you need to do is do `in.submit()` on any element in the form.

Comment: @JeffC no the Ajax only gets triggered on click of i would submit, the page would reload...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in.get_attribute('id')` to retrieve the `id`.

---

Alternatively, you can also select the `following-sibling::button` of a given element using an XPath:

```
in.find_element_by_xpath(".//following-sibling::button").click()
```

Explanation:

- `.` - Selects the current node (`<input>`)
- `//` - Selects nodes in the document

  - `following-sibling::button` - where siblings after the current node is a `<button>`

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second part is exactly what I'm looking for.