# How to search for an element in the same class as another (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

If I have already searched for an element, is there any way I can find another in the same class?

ex.

```
<div class="day">
  <span class="day_number">4</span>
  <span class="day_item_time" data-day-total-time="day-total-time">10m</span></div>
```

So I had to search by the date (finding the element that had the 4), but how do I translate that to finding the 10m?

This was the result after printing out the element `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="4ff20f1a-75d1-42c1-a7d0-de0c532651a6", element="1147f2d5-8832-44d4-a906-929ebaaa49e2")>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find next sibling element in Selenium, Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887592/find-next-sibling-element-in-selenium-python)

Comment: @birophilo: Not a dupe, elements of the same class are not necessarily siblings (and *vice versa*).

Answer (score 2):

Try This below code.It should return your expected output.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='day']/span)[1]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='day']/span)[2]").text
```

Output:

```
4
10m
```

Comment: The problem is that the "4" thats showing the day is on a calendar, so where im trying to find it will change :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
//span[text()="4"]/following-sibling::span
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `day-total-time` using xpaths below.

---

Get `span` with `day_number` class and text `4`, `ancestor` - get first parent `div` with class `day` and then get `span` with `data-day-total-time` attribute:

```
//span[@class='day_number' and .='4']/ancestor::div[@class='day'][1]/span[@data-day-total-time]
```

---

Get `div` with class `day` and child `span` with `day_number` class and text `4` and and then get `span` with `data-day-total-time` attribute:

```
//div[@class='day' and ./span[@class='day_number' and .='4']]/span[@data-day-total-time]
```