# Selenium: How to select each picture in a dynamically changing page?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

My situation is the following: I am writing a bot to automate scrolling through instagrams explore page. I want to like the first 100 pictures that appear for a given hashtag.

I am using: Selenium, python, chrome.

My problem is the following: Whenever I scroll, new posts “appear” and old ones “disappear”. I am using an xpath like this: //article[row]. However, this only works for the first 10 rows since then row 11 is actually row 8 because previous pictures that I have already passed do no longer appear on the same level.

Does somehow know how to handle such a situation? I would like to access every single picture in a dynamically changing page where new pictures are added when I scroll down and older ones disappear.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please share your code trials including the link to the page you working on. Otherwise this question is missing minimal debugging details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance I found an answer to this question: [Find next sibling element in Selenium, Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887592/find-next-sibling-element-in-selenium-python)

Basically you have to use JS:
next_sibling = driver.execute_script("""return arguments[0].nextElementSibling
""", element)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use a loop.

pseudocode:

```py
posts = []
while something:
   posts.extend(driver.find_posts())
   driver.scroll_till_current_posts_disappeared
```

for scrolling, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508235/20443541

Comment: Yes, I understand this. My problem is not the scrolling aspect or the loop. My problem is how to control the scrolling and how to make sure I only select images that haven't been selected previously. I appreciate the pseudocode but it doesn't help me much.

Comment: See below for the answer